# Stop window scroll with keycode (arrows), event.preventDefault() not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I built an autosuggest, and keycode works to navigate up and down through the list, but it scrolls the window. I have tried event.preventDefault() but it is not stopping it. Any ideas? This is what I have tried:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
e.returnValue=false;
e.preventDefault();
switch(e.keyCode) {
    case 40:
        suggestionLine++;
                $('#suggestionLine_'+suggestionLine).focus();
                break;
// etc...
```

Thank you!

Comment: tried return false instead of e.returnValue=false;?

Comment: like @TheSureshAtta at the bottom of your function put `return false;` instead of your `e.returnValue = false;`

Comment: you need both e.preventDefault(); and e.stopPropagation();

Comment: I tried return false, and e.stopPropagation(); still scrolling! I've looked all over the web. I'm out of ideas!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need `keydown`, not `keyup`.

Why? The default operation that you're trying to prevent happens immediately when you press the key (try it now!). This allows for things like autorepeat, which will send multiple `keydown` events before sending a single `keyup` event. By the time `keyup` is fired, the scrolling has already taken place.

Comment: There it is! Thank you very much!